# Target Framework only shows up to API 23

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I can't seem to select other API higher than Marshmallow

[image]

It is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105187/visual-studio-not-showing-installed-android-api-levels) than the framework that you can select depends on the version of Xamarin, but my version is already v8.x

[image]

Other forums also said to install the SDK Platform for your target framework, but even if I installed API 27, it still didn't show up in the target framework

[image]

I also updated the tools to the latest version

[image]

How to add the other API to the selection? What other things did I missed?

Comment: Can't really tell, but API 27 is not supported yet. Do you have 23-26 installed?

Comment: @JonDouglas I skipped the other API between 23 and 27, thinking that since I only need the latest SDK so that I can create a Xamarin.Forms project

Comment: You can install API 26 in this case then.

Comment: @JonDouglas API 26 appeared in the target framework, so that means API 27 is still not supported?