# Unable to change Target Framework despite having more up to date SDK's installed

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating a cross-platform app using a blank app template.

When I try compile I get some errors that are all around the $(targetframeworkversion) for "xamarin.forms.platform.android.dll (v7.1) is greater than the target framework version for your project(6.0)"

Ive been into the SDK manager and downloaded up to and including Android 9 (API 28) but when I go into the properties there only options that appear here are Android 6, so I cant change my target framework. I have tried restarting Visual Studio but the option is still only 6.0.

Could anyone let me know if Im missing a step, or alternate ways to resolve.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could try this to change target framework version:

right click your **project.Android** -> **Properties** -> **Application** -> **Compile using Android version (Target Framework)** -> select **Android 7.1** or later

or edit **.csproj** file,change to `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

If it still doesn't work,you could refer to this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118093/10768653

**PS**:Xamarin.Android uses JDK 8, which is required if you are developing for API level 24 or greater (JDK 8 also supports API levels earlier than 24).